# Drug-testing on background

Tags: employment, privacy, corporate-law, workplace, right-of-publicity

What sort of circumstances would allow a company or lab to put a positive pre-employment drug test on your background or send it to a consumer report agency? I'm curious about the consequences of failing such a drug test - specifically in Minnesota.